# Can you set a cookie to a method that has quotation marks?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a cookie to the code below because I want to take username information from one account creation page to a login page.

`document.cookie = "username = document.getElementById("username-input").value"`

However, the quotes in the `getElementById` method are messing up the cookie syntax. Is there any way to write this differently?

I tried removing the quotes, but I tested the code and it didn't work. I have also declared the `username` variable already and am altering it to equal HTML input.

To add: I tried the suggestions in the comments, and I don't know if they worked or not due to me being new to Javascript. The code I'm using to interpret the cookies is:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");

    for(var i = 0; i <cookieArr.length; i++) {
        var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");

        if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
            return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
        }
    }
}


let username = getCookie("username");
let password = getCookie("password");
```

Would it be possible for y'all to check the code above to make sure I'm getting the cookie at all? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: try to use single quote inside the string.

Comment: seems you want something like `document.cookie = \`username = ${document.getElementById("username-input").value}\``

Comment: Never store usernames or passwords into cookies. Post the credentials to your login page using a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element.

Comment: I know it's bad practice, but I'm just doing this for a fun project and not for real, so if there is a way to do it with cookies that would be great

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("username-input").value` is container which contains a string value but it is not a string itself. So you have to concatenate its value to your strings like this:

```
document.cookie = "username =" + document.getElementById("username-input").value;
```